# R Shiny MySql window authentication

Tags: mysql, r, authentication, shiny

I am working on an application on R- Shiny. I am using MySql as my database. So, I want application to connect to Database using windows authentication.

A explanation/link to a working example would be great :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [RMySQL](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html) package for this.
If you have MySQL running as a server and your fine with not using Windows authentication.

```
library(RMySQL)
# Connect to database
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), host = "localhost",
                 user = "myuser", password = "mypswd", dbname="mydb")
# Query database
out <- dbSendQuery(con, "select * from Data")
# Fetch all results
res <- fetch(out, n = -1)
```

Just change the user, password and database to what you want to use.

If you want to configure some custom settings for the MySQL client you can set default.file=mycnf.cnf in dbConnect and use [these](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_secure-auth) options